# php html input text field

Tags: javascript, php, html

The user sets through the field an inequality, i.e. `50<A, X>30, 50<C<100`. This is stored through javascript function on button click.

My issue is, the field doesn't work in a specific case when there's a "less than" symbol followed by a letter. So, it will store fine e.g. `X>30, A<50, but NOT 50<A or 50<C<100`. In both of the latter cases it just shows the first number, meaning it's having trouble with the pattern "less than followed by letter", as this is simply omitted. How do I make it work?

Here's my code (php):

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"equation\">";
echo "<button onclick=\"addEq()\">Add</button>";
```

And javascript part (basically appends all equations entered, separated by ":")

```
var addEq = function() {
    eq = document.getElementById("equation").value;
    if (document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML == "") {
        document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML = eq;}
    else {
        document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML += ":" + eq;}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `<` in your inequalities with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.
With `<` and a letter, the browser is trying to render it as html because it thinks it's a tag (like `<a>`).

```js
var addEq = function() {
    eq = document.getElementById("equation").value.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
    if (document.getElementById("result").innerHTML == "") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = eq;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += ":" + eq;
    }
}
function getResult() {
    var res = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML.replace(/&lt;/g, '<');
    console.log(res);
    return res;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="equation" value="50<C<100">
<button onclick="addEq()">Add</button>
<button onclick="getResult()">Result</button>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: where exactly in the code? I am passing the string forward so I need to have it in that format

Comment: I've added an example that does the replacing, and also provides a way to get the raw string back from the displayed inequalities.